# Remove json field (when empty value) in serialize with json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

What is the best practice to remove json field (when empty value) with serialize using json4s?

```
val json = ("foo" -> "bar") ~ ("fizz" -> "buzz")
compact(render(json))
""" {"foo":"bar","fizz":"buzz"} """


val json = ("foo" -> "bar") ~ ("fizz" -> "")
compact(render(json))
""" {"foo":"bar"} """
```

Comment: Hint - Writing some code will certainly help.

Answer (score 0):

1. using EmptyValueStrategy (if you serialize JValue)

```scala
val formats = DefaultFormats.withEmptyValueStrategy(new EmptyValueStrategy {

  def noneValReplacement = None

  def replaceEmpty(value: JValue): JValue = {
    case JString("") => JNothing
    case JArray(items) => JArray(items map replaceEmpty)
    case JObject(fields) => JObject(fields map {
      case JField(name, v) => JField(name, replaceEmpty(v))
    })
    case oth => oth
  }
})
compact(render(("foo" -> "bar") ~ ("fizz" -> "")))
```

2. using CustomSerializer (if you serialize case class)

```scala
val customSerializer = new CustomSerializer[String](_ => ({ case JString(s) => s }, { case "" => JNothing case s: String => JString(s) }))
implicit val jsonFormat = DefaultFormats + customSeirializer

case class Foo(a: Int, b: String)
Serialization.write(Foo(42, ""))
```